# How Can I Change the Icon for an Existing Shortcut in shell script

Tags: macos, shell, icons, shortcut

I have installed my flash application using packagemaker installer. I have created short cut to desktop using shell Script. Now i want to change the default short cut Icon. Please tell me shell script to change the short cut icon.

MAC OS 10.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X doesn't have "shortcut files".  It has either alias files or symbolic links (symlinks).

I imagine that you created a symlink, since you're working from a shell.  Symlinks can't have custom icons.  They have almost no real data or metadata of their own.

I don't know of a way to set an icon for an alias file (or any other file) from the shell. My first thought was AppleScript, which you can use from a shell via the `osascript` command. But I find that the Finder's AppleScript support does not include working with file icons.  There's a definition of an `icon family` class, but it's marked as "NOT AVAILABLE YET".